# angular component not receiving state data if it's used second time

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-router, angular-state-managmement

I am passing data from route with state but component is receiving it only first time, how I can listen it to every time component is visible.

```
 const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
  state: { billingInfoData: billinfoData },
};

this.router.navigate(['/tabs/mytab'], navigationExtras);
```

receiving code is like below in constructor

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(data => {
      console.error(data);
      this.setSubtitle(data);

      if (
        this.router.getCurrentNavigation() &&
        this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state
      ) {

      console.error(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state);

      }
    });
```

Comment: Could you add how you are getting your data ? is it in the `ngInit` ?

Comment: @Nicolas added in question

Comment: could you recreate the issue on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

You could try to subscribe to NavigationEnd event from your router and add your state in a hook like ngOnInit in a component that outlive your mytab components:

```
this.router.events.subscribe( (navEvent)=> {
  if (navEvent instanceof NavigationEnd && navEvent.url.includes('/tabs/mytab')) {
    this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state = navigationExtras;
  }
});
```